# Type constraint on generic dictionary

Tags: c#, generics

I am using reflection to find a constructor of a given type. I then would like to cache the constructor keyed on its type so that I can use it on the fly the next time that constructor is needed. The code below does so but it requires me to store the constructor as is was returning an object, and then casting it to the desired type. I was hoping there was a way to make it more type safe.

```
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<Guid, object>> AggregateConstructors = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<Guid, object>>();

public TAggregate GetAggregate<TAggregate>(Guid aggregateId) where TAggregate : AggregateRoot
{
    var constructor = AggregateConstructors.GetOrAdd(typeof(TAggregate), GetConstructorFunc<TAggregate>());
    // Requires a cast.  
    var aggregate = (TAggregate)constructor(aggregateId);

    var history = eventStore.GetDomainEvents(aggregateId);
    aggregate.LoadFromHistory(history);

    return aggregate;
}

private Func<Guid, TAggregate> GetConstructorFunc<TAggregate>()
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Guid), "aggregateId");
    var constructor = typeof(TAggregate).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(Guid) });
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Guid, TAggregate>>(Expression.New(constructor, parameter), parameter);
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

I would like to have something along these lines:

```
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<Guid, SameTypeAsKey>> AggregateConstructors = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<Guid, SameTypeAsKey>>();

public TAggregate GetAggregate<TAggregate>(Guid aggregateId) where TAggregate : AggregateRoot
{
    var constructor = AggregateConstructors.GetOrAdd(typeof(TAggregate), GetConstructorFunc<TAggregate>());
    var aggregate = constructor(aggregateId);

    var history = eventStore.GetDomainEvents(aggregateId);
    aggregate.LoadFromHistory(history);

    return aggregate;
}

private Func<Guid, TAggregate> GetConstructorFunc<TAggregate>()
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Guid), "aggregateId");
    var constructor = typeof(TAggregate).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(Guid) });
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Guid, TAggregate>>(Expression.New(constructor, parameter), parameter);
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do this. The first code is ok and does not require improvements.

Another idea for you is to use generic class with static field instead of concurrent dictionary:

```
static class AggregateConstructors<TAggregate>
{
    public static Func<Guid, TAggregate> Value { get; private set; }
    public static TAggregate Create(Guid aggregateId) => Value(aggregateId);

    static AggregateConstructors()
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Guid), "aggregateId");
        var constructor = typeof(TAggregate).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(Guid) });
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Guid, TAggregate>>(Expression.New(constructor, parameter), parameter);
        Value = lambda.Compile();
    }
}

public TAggregate GetAggregate<TAggregate>(Guid aggregateId) where TAggregate : AggregateRoot
{
    var aggregate = AggregateConstructors<TAggregate>.Create(aggregateId);

    var history = eventStore.GetDomainEvents(aggregateId);
    aggregate.LoadFromHistory(history);

    return aggregate;
}
```

But note that static variables in generic classes are not recommended to use.

Answer (score 0):

One option is you just need to add another layer that goes over the dictionary that does the cast for you. This could easily be a extension method

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static Func<Guid, TAggregate> GetOrAdd<TAggregate>(this ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<Guid, object>> @this, Func<Guid, TAggregate> factory)
    {
        var constructor = @this.GetOrAdd(typeof(TAggregate), (key) => factory);
        return (guid) => (TAggregate)constructor(guid);
    }
}
```

This lets you do

```
public TAggregate GetAggregate<TAggregate>(Guid aggregateId) where TAggregate : AggregateRoot
{
    var constructor = AggregateConstructors.GetOrAdd<TAggregate>(GetConstructorFunc<TAggregate>());
    var aggregate = constructor(aggregateId);

    var history = eventStore.GetDomainEvents(aggregateId);
    aggregate.LoadFromHistory(history);

    return aggregate;
}
```

Another option is if `LoadFromHistory` is a function on the base `AggregateRoot` class you could just replace `object` with `AggregateRoot` then move the cast to the end of the method.

```
public TAggregate GetAggregate<TAggregate>(Guid aggregateId) where TAggregate : AggregateRoot
{
    var constructor = AggregateConstructors.GetOrAdd(typeof(TAggregate), GetConstructorFunc<TAggregate>());
    // Requires a cast.  
    var aggregate = constructor(aggregateId);

    var history = eventStore.GetDomainEvents(aggregateId);
    aggregate.LoadFromHistory(history);

    return (TAggregate)aggregate;
}
```